# unable to run npm command. tty.js not installing

Tags: node.js, npm, tty, adobe-brackets

I am working on an application that extends Adobe brackets. Here I need to add terminal/console in that. I have installed node.js and npm server already.

Now i need to run `npm install -g tty.js` command but it show me this error
[image]

Comment: Can you install anything else? e.g. npm install express just to see if you get an error too

Comment: @deeveeABC yes did. it run fine

Comment: This can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32447102/node-gyp-problems-build-and-rebuild-windows-8-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

work-round->
try without -g, this will @least install on local dir. more over u need 2 come in terms with npm support team.

email support@npmjs.com to get your copy of this package..

you can also work with stand-alone copies available on i-net.. here is one such link where you can find full source-code for term.js..

https://github.com/chjj/term.js/blob/master/src/term.js

OR

install web-terminal package from npm, with CLI use command : 'sudo npm install web-terminal -g'